# How can I download encrypted .gz file from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I backup a nextcloud instance, compress and encrypt it and the I store it in an S3 bucket. When I enter the bucket I have a file called `backup.tar.gz`. Great.

Now I download the file form the bucket and I get a  `.tar` file, which obviously renders my backup completely useless. I can't decrypt it. If I manually save the file with the extension `.gz` it still doesn't decrypt but says `tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format`.

When I try to download it via the CLI it doesn't download the file but says `usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]`:

`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile.tar.gz`

The problem is mentioned also here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=250926 where the only answer is, "why not use AWS snapshot to backup your EC2 instance".

I don't get why AWS would do that or is this a bug? Is there any decent way to get my backup from my bucket in the format I specify?

I could also do this, if necessary with a python script but IDK if that would work any better?

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

I encrypt like this:

```
tar -czf - /path/to/file | openssl enc -e -aes256 -pbkdf2 -salt -out backup.tar.gz -pass pass:$ENCRYPTION_PASS
```

Comment: I think this question is off-topic here. The tag description for bash says *Questions about interactive use of Bash are more likely to be on-topic on Super User than on Stack Overflow.*, haven't you seen it?

Comment: Yes tbh I thought about putting it on superuser first but then went with SO cause there are a bunch of questions on AWS S3... I can move it there though

Comment: Also I don't really want to have advice on how to write bash, just included the tag since I have some bash in there

Comment: Okay then. I'd say wait a couple hours before moving this to superuser if you're not in a hurry

Comment: Yes, ok will do it like this, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by getting your backup from your bucket "in the format I specify"? The file stored in S3 is what it is. If you uploaded a tar.gz then that's what it is. When you download it, it doesn't change. And to copy a file from S3, use `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile.tar.gz .` (with a dot) or `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile.tar.gz xyz.tar.gz`.

Comment: @jarmod, thanks for your input, I'm still verifying this but it seems like you are right and my problem was an env variable that wasn't read... I'll get back here soon

Comment: @jarmod ok you are absolutely right. I'm stupid. With the terminal it works like you said without a problem and in gives me the .gz file. My password wasn't read and I was looking in the wrong direction. Yet, just for completeness sake: If I download the .gz file in the browser it is not what it is. It downloads as .tar file. But that doesn't matter, the terminal is better for my usecase anyways. Thanks a bunch, you made me look the right way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a file from S3 using the awscli as follows:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile.tar.gz .
```

Note the trailing period which means 'to the current folder'.

Or you could rename the file during download, as follows:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile.tar.gz xyz.tar.gz
```

It's possible, I suppose, that if you download a tar.gz using a browser or other tool (not the awscli) then that tool might try to be helpful and uncompress the GZ file for you in flight, resulting in a TAR file. But the `awscli` won't do that natively.